# How do you implement local invalidation/purging securely?

Tags: security, software-design

If we look at Youtube's (with a YT Premium subscription) offline video implementation for their mobile app, it says that "downloaded" videos will remain available for up to 30 days of continual lack of internet connectivity, after which, the videos will be unviewable:

> Downloaded videos renew automatically as long as you go online in your home country/region at least once every 30 days.

And based on the quote above, this 30 day purge/invalidation timer seems to be refreshed every time the user manages to establish an internet connection.

How do you implement this kind of functionality in a secure and tamper-proof manner, considering that there is no internet connection available. Sure, I guess you could store some sort of encrypted value locally that says when to invalidate, but then obviously the key would have to be stored locally too (so the application can decrypt the invalidation time upon opening) and be susceptible for the user to find and update the encrypted value to their benefit and delay the invalidation time. And I guess that would go for any other kind of 'secret' that gets stored locally.

Comment: The invalidation time should not have to be secret, in this case you should only renew the timer when you are connected to the corresponding region, if this does not happen and 30 days pass then you delete the local data.

Comment: In that situation, where would the timer live? Since the app could be killed and restarted at anytime, the timer sounds circumventable.